# How to check the edittext Listener is remove or not

Tags: android, android-edittext

I am using the the two `editext` and add the seperate `textWatcher` classes object
when some one give the focus then second one `textListener` is remove.

Then
**My Question is how to check the textListener is add or remove**

thnax in advance

Comment: what do you mean? "check the textListener is add or remove" ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

AFAIK, There is no method to get the current assigne TextWatcher instance of the EditText object.

Rather you just can do like,

```
mEdiText.addTextChangedListener(null);
```

before you assign any `TextWatcher` and then assign the Watcher object `mEdiText.addTextChangedListener(new MyTextWatcher());` to the EditText in any event or any condition.

Assigning `null` will remove the previous TextWatcher.

And to know is it really worked or not, just run your app and test it once.

Comment: what does your comments says..!?!?!